cam -l segmentation fault (core dumped)
Ubuntu 22.04
Pi Zero 2 W
I have updated / upgraded and added a swap file. Previous attempts to compile from source make no difference.
dpkg -l | grep libcamera
ii libcamera-dev:arm64 0~git20200629+e7aa92a-9 arm64 complex camera support library (development files)
ii libcamera-tools 0~git20200629+e7aa92a-9 arm64 complex camera support library (tools)
ii libcamera0:arm64 0~git20200629+e7aa92a-9 arm64 complex camera support library

cam -l
Segmentation fault (core dumped)

libcamera-hello
libcamera-hello: command not found

I have verified the hardware with Bullseye, but need to use Ubuntu because I want to use ROS2.
Any help would be appreciated.
As suggested below I ran the commands, these are the results:
type -a cam
cam is /usr/bin/cam
cam is /bin/cam

ldd /usr/bin/cam
    linux-vdso.so.1 (0x0000ffffa7972000)
    libcamera.so.0 => /lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libcamera.so.0 (0x0000ffffa7820000)
    libstdc++.so.6 => /lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 (0x0000ffffa75f0000)
    libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x0000ffffa75c0000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x0000ffffa7410000)
    /lib/ld-linux-aarch64.so.1 (0x0000ffffa7939000)
    libgnutls.so.30 => /lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libgnutls.so.30 (0x0000ffffa7200000)
    libudev.so.1 => /lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libudev.so.1 (0x0000ffffa71c0000)
    libm.so.6 => /lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0x0000ffffa7120000)
    libp11-kit.so.0 => /lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libp11-kit.so.0 (0x0000ffffa6fd0000)
    libidn2.so.0 => /lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libidn2.so.0 (0x0000ffffa6fa0000)
    libunistring.so.2 => /lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libunistring.so.2 (0x0000ffffa6de0000)
    libtasn1.so.6 => /lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libtasn1.so.6 (0x0000ffffa6db0000)
    libnettle.so.8 => /lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libnettle.so.8 (0x0000ffffa6d50000)
    libhogweed.so.6 => /lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libhogweed.so.6 (0x0000ffffa6cf0000)
    libgmp.so.10 => /lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libgmp.so.10 (0x0000ffffa6c60000)
    libffi.so.8 => /lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libffi.so.8 (0x0000ffffa6c40000)

ldd /bin/cam
    linux-vdso.so.1 (0x0000ffff92341000)
    libcamera.so.0 => /lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libcamera.so.0 (0x0000ffff921f0000)
    libstdc++.so.6 => /lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 (0x0000ffff91fc0000)
    libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x0000ffff91f90000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x0000ffff91de0000)
    /lib/ld-linux-aarch64.so.1 (0x0000ffff92308000)
    libgnutls.so.30 => /lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libgnutls.so.30 (0x0000ffff91bd0000)
    libudev.so.1 => /lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libudev.so.1 (0x0000ffff91b90000)
    libm.so.6 => /lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0x0000ffff91af0000)
    libp11-kit.so.0 => /lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libp11-kit.so.0 (0x0000ffff919a0000)
    libidn2.so.0 => /lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libidn2.so.0 (0x0000ffff91970000)
    libunistring.so.2 => /lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libunistring.so.2 (0x0000ffff917b0000)
    libtasn1.so.6 => /lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libtasn1.so.6 (0x0000ffff91780000)
    libnettle.so.8 => /lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libnettle.so.8 (0x0000ffff91720000)
    libhogweed.so.6 => /lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libhogweed.so.6 (0x0000ffff916c0000)
    libgmp.so.10 => /lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libgmp.so.10 (0x0000ffff91630000)
    libffi.so.8 => /lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libffi.so.8 (0x0000ffff91610000)


The first troubleshooting steps that come to mind are (1) check that cam is in the location you expect e.g. type -a cam and (2) check that it is linking the libraries that you expect e.g. ldd /usr/bin/cam

type -a cam
cam is /usr/bin/cam
cam is /bin/cam
Should I delete one? Or is this expected?

That's expected - /bin is a symbolic link to /usr/bin as a result of usrmerge
